# Programa no Lazarus não executa com .SO compartilhada

Tags: linux, lazarus

Tive um problema com SO compartilhada em um projeto no Linux com Lazarus, encontrei a solução em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s

Após executar a orientações acima a minha aplicação passou a funcionar, entretanto não consigo executa-lá pelo lazarus (compila normal, mas não abre e não exibe mensagem de erro), conseguindo executar apenas pelo terminal.

Acredito que o problema esteja relacionado a chamada da SO, pois quando eu retiro essa chamada, a aplicação funciona normalmente.

Uso a versão 1.2.6 do Lazarus e Linux Debian 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida que eu tive, vou deixa a solução que eu encontrei:

Movi as libs que estavam no diretório do projeto para o diretório /usr/lib e dei permissão de leitura e escrita, desse modo não foi preciso fazer nenhuma configuração a mais.